# How to cite more than two authors using .bib in a report?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How to cite more than two authors using `.bib` in a report? I want my output to be in the form of (Feynman et al. 2005).

My code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nty{}]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

bla, bla, bla \textcite{Feynman}

\end{document}
```

And the citing is given here as:

```
@inbook{Feynman,
    author = { R. P. Feynman, R. B. Leighton, M. W. Sands},
    title = {The Feynman Lectures on Physics:The Definitive and Extended Edition },
    publisher = {Addison Wesley},
    year = {2005}
}
```

Comment: The names should not be separated by commas but by "and". So try `author = { R. P. Feynman and R. B. Leighton and M. W. Sands}`

Comment: Thanks Oleinik, I got this output after I changed the comma:(Feynman, Leighton, and Sands 2005) however, I want the output in form of Feynman et al., what citing command should I use?

Comment: How the citation call out is formated will depend on your settings. For us to be able to help, we need more information. Please post a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), beginning with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}` and including a couple of bib entries. Do so by editing your question (you can see the option to edit on the bottom left of the question).

Comment: Probably you want`\usepackage[maxcitenames=1,…]{biblatex}`. Other relevant options are `maxnames` and `maxbibnames`. See the `biblatex` manual for details.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, it works now. the comments were all important

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

- You should specify your author as `author = {Feynman, R. P. and Leighton, R. B. and Sands, M. W.}` (i.e., Family, Given and Family, Given and …) You could also put full names in your bib file and use the `giveninits` option for `biblatex` which will automatically just print initials in your bibliography.
- Add `maxcitenames=1` to your `biblatex` options. Depending on what you want, you could use `maxnames=1` which will also set it for the bibliography. The number of names printed in the bibliography can be controlled separately using the `maxbibnames` option. There are also corresponding `minnames`, `mincitenames`, and `minbibnames` options.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Feynman,
  author    = {Feynman, R. P. and Leighton, R. B. and Sands, M. W.},
  title     = {The Feynman Lectures on Physics: The Definitive and Extended Edition},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  date      = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nty,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
bla, bla, bla \textcite{Feynman}
\end{document}
```

[image]